# Why does my div go higher with each additional link?

Tags: html, css

The more links I add inside my div#links the higher it goes relatively to other divs. Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/8n07eans/

```
<body>
    <div id="pageWrapper">
        <div id="plan">
            <div class="heading">
                Plan
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
            <div class="heading">
                Links 1
            </div>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a><br/>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
            <div class="heading">
                Links 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
            <div class="heading">
                Links 3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="notes">
            <div class="heading">
                Notes
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
            <div class="heading">
                Links 3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="gallery">
            <div class="heading">
                Gallery
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--end pageWrapper-->
</body>
</html>



* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(30,30,30);
}

#pageWrapper {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 650px;
    background-color: rgb(30,30,30);
    color: rgb(230,230,230);
    margin: 10px auto 0px auto;;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: rgb(184,216,5);
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    color: rgb(184,216,5);
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#plan , #notes, #gallery{
    border: 3px solid rgb(230,230,230);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 452px;
    height: 280px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.links {
    border: 3px solid rgb(230,230,230);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 215px;
    height: 280px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.heading {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0px auto 5px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.links a {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` to the `.links` class. Should make all the divs align together.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the following property :

```
    vertical-align: top;
```

So, just modify your `#plan, #notes, #gallery` and `links`class as follows :

```
#plan, #notes, #gallery {
    border: 3px solid #E6E6E6;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 452px;
    height: 280px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 5px 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

See this working below :

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border: none;
}

body {
 background-color: rgb(30,30,30);
}

#pageWrapper {
 width: 1200px;
 height: 650px;
 background-color: rgb(30,30,30);
 color: rgb(230,230,230);
 margin: 10px auto 0px auto;;
 font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 padding: 20px 0px;
}

a:link, a:visited {
 color: rgb(184,216,5);
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
 color: rgb(184,216,5);
 text-decoration: underline;
}

#plan , #notes, #gallery{
 border: 3px solid rgb(230,230,230);
 border-radius: 10px;
 width: 452px;
 height: 280px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.links {
 border: 3px solid rgb(230,230,230);
 border-radius: 10px;
 width: 215px;
 height: 280px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.heading {
 width: 150px;
 margin: 0px auto 5px auto;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 0.8em;
}

.links a {
 margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="pageWrapper">
  <div id="plan">
   <div class="heading">
    Plan
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="links">
   <div class="heading">
    Links 1
   </div>
   <a href="#">Link 1</a><br/>
   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="links">
   <div class="heading">
    Links 2
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="links">
   <div class="heading">
    Links 3
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="notes">
   <div class="heading">
    Notes
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="links">
   <div class="heading">
    Links 3
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="gallery">
   <div class="heading">
    Gallery
   </div>
  </div>
 </div><!--end pageWrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```